# Cleaner, less fragile way to reference a UICollectionView header supplementary view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Currently I'm referencing a UICollectionView header inside of my UICollectionViewController subclass, like so:

```
class HeaderCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Register header view XIB
        collectionView?.register(UINib(nibName: headerNibName, bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerReuseIdentifier)

        // Configure header view height
        headerView?.height = HeaderViewHeight(
            origin: 250.0,
            max: UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        )

    }

    var headerView: HeaderView? {
        // Convenience getter for HeaderView
        get {
            guard let headerView = collectionView?.supplementaryView(forElementKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) as? HeaderView else { return nil }
            return headerView
        }
    }

}
```

That getter seems inordinately long, and seems rather fragile too.

Is there a cleaner way to reference the header supplementary view? Or is this the only way?

Is there some way I can leverage the dequeuing mechanism to store it (since I'm already retrieving it?)

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let headerView: HeaderView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! HeaderView
    return headerView
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get rid of using `headerView` as a computed property and just assign to it `HeaderView` created in `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` method. If you only need to configure its height, you can use `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(
        width: collectionView?.bounds.width,
        height: someHeaderViewHeight
    )
}
```

Comment: I definitely need a strong reference to it for use elsewhere in the controller.

Comment: Is there anything standing in your way to use stored variable instead of computed one?

Comment: I don’t think so, but even then, I’d still have to retrieve it this way...?

Comment: Yes, you’ll have to use `dequeueReusableSupplementaryView` but still there are some possible improvements:

1. Check `kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader` to be sure that the collection view is requesting header view.

2. Use `as?` with optional binding instead of `as!`

3. Get rid of explicit `ReuseIdentifier`. Check [here](https://medium.com/@gonzalezreal/ios-cell-registration-reusing-with-swift-protocol-extensions-and-generics-c5ac4fb5b75e) how to do it.